# Can you attach a workflow to a web part?

Tags: 2010, web-part, workflow

In sharepoint 2010, is it possible to attach a workflow to a particular web part so that it is run wherever that web part is inserted within your site.

For instance, I will be developing a large number of different pages to host videos (embedded from various sources including youtube and screencast). Because the videos will be hosted in external locations I will need to include a "report broken link" button, though I am reluctant to insert the image and turn it into a hyperlink on every one of the pages. So would it be possible to create this button in a web part and attach a workflow (say, to email me when it is clicked) to it so that all I have to do is insert the web part on each page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest rather go for a feedback/comments list (e.g. Top-Level site per site collection), and use either DVWP to enable users to submit feedback, or via a CEWP you could easily rely on ECMAScript in SharePoint 2010 to insert items at a button click (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185011.aspx).

In the 2nd step you could easily attach an email workflow made with SharePoint Designer which would drop a mail everytime you have a new entry in the list (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/send-e-mail-in-a-workflow-HA010239042.aspx).

This way you decouple the 2, and you could use the list for tracking and other scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be ok to instead of attaching a workflow to the web part to actually make the web part start a workflow? To me that sounds like a better idea. And you could make a list that the Web Part create on deployment, where you can configure what workflow it should start when activated.

Comment: This would be difficult to re-use though would it not? Not all the videos are within one site but right across a site collection. I have been unable to transfer things, via workflow, between sites before. I like your idea, though it would still mean creating lists within every site, in which case I may as well write the link.
Please correct me if I have mis-understood.

Comment: I don't think i understand. You don't want to create a button or a link to report a broken link. So i would like to sort out what are you doing? How are the users going to report broken links?

Comment: I want to create a button, but I only want to create it once. So instead of having to insert the picture, select it, add a hyperlink etc. on every page; I'd like to do it once, in a web part. 
I suppose I could have it linked to an empty page hosting the workflow to send the email and use javascript to redirect them back...